# Meaning of star/asterisk in linguistics

Tags: terminology

In some dictionaries/lexica, I've seen the asterisk in front of old words. What does it mean/stand for?

Example: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proto-Germanic#Pre-Proto-Germanic

> *ǵʰóstis "stranger" > *gʰóstis > *gastiz "guest"

Answer (score 31, accepted):

An asterisk is generally used to indicate that a certain form or construction is **not found in natural language**. To be precise, it means there is insufficient evidence to assume that it could exist or could once have existed in natural language.

When describing **proto-languages**, this usually means that a certain root or word has been reconstructed: based on phonological rules, we think it must have been somewhat like this—but we cannot be sure, as it is always possible that some unique irregularity would result in a different form, and we have no written sources that contain this form. When a form has never been found in a real source, we say it has not been attested; in other words, it is **unattested**. In most proto-languages, *all* forms are hypothetical, so that they should all be preceded by an asterisk.

With **modern languages**, we usually have plenty of sources to establish whether a certain form is possible. In fact, many linguists make up example sentences when they need to, because many forms and constructions are not at all controversial. So I might use *Achilles hated Hector* in an article if I needed an example. However, I may also want to use an example that is ungrammatical, i.e. that I believe would never be used naturally in the language under observation. Then I would put an asterisk in front of it:

> *Achilles did hated Hector.

Note that it depends on context whether a construction is grammatical: if I were writing about standard English, I'd have to use an asterisk; but, if I were writing about a certain dialect where this construction is actually used by some, the asterisk is out of place.

Note also that "natural language" is a flexible and sometimes unclear concept; if you are researching English poetry of the 16th century, it is much harder to acquire enough evidence than with modern prose. Context or explanation should make it clear what *natural language* is supposed to be in a certain text.

---

Most people would use a question mark instead of an asterisk with well-attested languages if the form or construction is doubtful. In proto-languages, the question mark is sometimes used to indicate a form that is even *more* uncertain than the common hypothetical ones—for example, if I am in doubt as to the most probable form of a certain root.

Some people use the percentage sign to mark something that is only grammatical in a certain non-standard dialect.

Comment: So, in summary, * means wrong in current standard, expected correct in historical reconstruction, and ? means questionable (but not obviously wrong or right) in current standard, and possible but not sure in historical reconstruction?

Comment: @Mitch: Yes, except that we have no way to assess correctness for reconstructed forms; the best we can do is follow historical phonological rules consistently. It is very well possible that none of those forms are exactly right. // When we are not sure what these phonological rules would point to, we use a question mark, or so I have always interpreted it. // I agree that the jump from prehistoric asterisk to modern asterisk is not entirely satisfying in all respects.

Answer (score 7):

It's true that an asterisk indicates a reconstructed word or morpheme in historical linguistics.

In theoretical linguistics, as Cerebus suggested, it indicates **ungrammaticality**. There are a few other such markers: question marks indicate **relative unacceptability**, and hash marks indicate anything from semantic incoherence (ex. (1c)) to **infelicity**, a pragmatic failure (ex. (1d)).

1.a. *John slept the baby.

b. ?John ate much rice.

c. #Colorless green ideas sleep furiously

d. #His horse sleeps until dawn. [In response to the question "How are you doing?"]

Answer (score 5):

In the context of historical linguistics, it means the word is just a hypothetical reconstruction, not an actually attested word.

(The asterisk has another meaning which is to mark an ungrammatical utterance)

Comment: This is why J. R. R. Tolkien referred to historical linguistics as "The Star-Spangled Grammar."